# How to pass DatabaseReference to class in android while using intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I'm using intent to call a service class which extends some other class (other than intent).

I want to pass DatabaseReference while calling the service class.

What could be the possible way to do that ? I've thought of using SharedPrefrences, but I'm not able to figure-out a way to pass context also.

It is possible to create database reference in new class too, but I'm using authentication in MainActivity, so doing this is also bit tricky.

My service class:

```
public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService {

     private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

}
```

Comment: why not a DatabaseReference instance? You get a instance of DatabaseReference from singleton pattern. You do not need to pass DatabaseReference as parameter.

Comment: @hjchin Didn't knew about that, can you explain a bit more. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming DatabaseReference is part of Firebase SDK,

in your NLService class

```
public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService {
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference myRef1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();     
}
```

Does it works for you?

Comment: Yes Indeed. Thanks a lot. PS: It seems I've very shallow knowledge in Android.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass DatabaseReference, you can use instance in your MainActivity as well.

```
class MainActivity{
   DatabaseReference myDBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

   if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) { 
      // do your task
   }
}
```